# uninitialized constant Test when running Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting `uninitialized constant Test` when running `rails console` in terminal. I'm not sure why I just set it up and using the command `rails server` works.

This is the error I get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>': uninitialized constant Test (NameError)
```

Comment: Can you give any more info? How did you install rails? Did you install or configure anything in a non standard way? Help us help you here.

Comment: Show the full error trace..

Comment: rails new bookmarks -T -d sqlite3 -B
that is what I ran to create a new rails app.
I'm using a linux os ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. Solved in the following way:

`sudo apt-get install  ruby-test-unit
echo require 'test/unit' >> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb`

see this link: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-activesupport-3.2/+bug/1319101

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when copied and pasted the config from [shoulda-matchers getting started guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers). But I wasn't removing the unused tests frameworks.

To use with RSpec it will be as:

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    with.test_framework :rspec
    # with.test_framework :minitest
    # with.test_framework :minitest_4
    # with.test_framework :test_unit

    # Choose one or more libraries:
    with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    with.library :action_controller
    # Or, choose the following (which implies all of the above):
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the echo command above may not work on all installs of Ubuntu 14.04. You can do a sudo vi and physically edit the test_case.rb file and put the require 'test/unit' after the existing require(s).

Answer (score 0):

First: Why are you not using [rvm](http://rvm.io) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/)? You can mess your operational system!

Second: It is not finding any reference to a class named Test. Are you sure is this the name? Have you properly required it? Which Test Framework are you using?